# Model looks weird in rendered view

Tags: modeling, rendering, shaders, transparency

I have modeled a googly eye and added a simple principled shader with full transmission but when I view it in rendered view, there is a weird black thing along it's edge. I have not encountered it before so I don't know what's causing it, the material or the model.

[image: Glitch]

Comment: It looks like you haven't assigned the white material to all faces.

Comment: I've assigned it. Actually I am using a white glossy+diffuse for the back faces and the transparent for the front faces.

Comment: When you add a Multiresolution Modifier to something which has already had its UVs laid out, you can get an effect like this. Make sure the UVs are as you want on the full res model.  And you could have normals flipped??

Comment: Actually I have not unwraped it since I am not using image textures and the materials are procedural. Also, there is no multires modifier. The normals are facing correctly.